# How to enable 64-bit support with GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, 64-bit, gpuimage

When building app with GPUImage, I got errors like this

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/.../GPUImage'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../Libraries/GPUImage/libGPUImage.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/.../Libraries/GPUImage/libGPUImage.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageCrosshatchFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AddPopViewController.o
```

I don't know if this error is related, but what I want to do is for my app to support 64-bit processors. How can I do that?
In this [link](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/commit/adf85c2324739b480928bab8ee4b5221739ecb65), it says

> The framework supports 64-bit, but you'll have to enable this for your project in the framework and your application yourself

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps given in the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1) to ensure the app supports 64 bit. Check if the following points are taken care in your environment.

At a high level, here are the steps to create an app that targets both the 32-bit and the 64-bit runtime environments:

> 1. **Install the latest Xcode.**
> 2. **Open your project.** Xcode prompts you to modernize your project. Modernizing the project adds new warnings and errors that are
>      important when compiling your app for 64-bit.
> 3. **Update your project settings to support iOS 5.1.1 or later.** You can’t build a 64-bit project if it targets an iOS version earlier than
>      iOS 5.1.
> 4. **Change the Architectures build setting in your project to "Standard Architectures (including 64-bit)."**
> 5. **Update your app to support the 64-bit runtime environment.** The new compiler warnings and errors will help guide you through this
>      process. However, the compiler doesn’t do all of the work for you; use
>      the information in this document to help guide you through
>      investigating your own code.
> 6. **Test your app on actual 64-bit hardware.** iOS Simulator can also be helpful during development, but some changes, such as the function
>      calling conventions, are visible only when your app is running on a
>      device.